# Bootstrap maxlength counting with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i have an editable div where I want to use the same maxlength counting system as at textareas/inputs from bootstrap.

I have the editable div:

```
<div id="editor" name="beschreibung2" class="form-control note-editable maxlength-beschreibung2" maxlength="123" contenteditable="true">123</div>
```

and add the maxlength:

```
$(function() { //Max-Length Beschreibung
$('.maxlength-beschreibung2').maxlength({
    alwaysShow: true,
    warningClass: "label label-primary",
    limitReachedClass: "label label-danger"
});
```

When I focus the div the little counting info is poping up, the maxlength is right but when I type in some stuff, the counting doenst work. Its always 0/123.
So is there a possible way to access to popup via JS/JQuery and put in my own numbers? So I can count the div by my own and just throw the numbers in?

Comment: Popup is yours or bootstraps? If it's your, then show us code

Comment: Its from bootstrap. Its a little box at the bottom of the input where you can see the actual number of chars and the max number of chars